# Link collision in React Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to implement 'Not Found' page to redirect user if the url is not valid. However, not found page link somehow collides with search results and redirects user to 'Not Found' after submitting search input.

- 'Search', 'Result' and 'Not Found' are different components and links
  are different.

**Browser Router code in parent app component**
(State for search results defined in here )

```
const [searchResult, setSearchResult] = useState([]);

<BrowserRouter>          
   <Switch>         
    <Route path=''> 
      <NotFound />
    </Route>
    <Route path='*'>
      <Redirect to ='/404' />
    </Route>
    <Route path='/search'>
      <Result 
      searchResult={searchResult}
      setSearchResult={setSearchResult}
       />
     </Route>
   </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

- In the current situation, search bar component works and shows
  results if I remove 'Not Found' from browser router.
- Search results are displayed in 'Result' component.

---

**Search Component**

**(If I remove first '/search', from history it doesn't work.)**

Search result link

```
> http://localhost:3000/search/search?q=adidas
```

Item is available and can be found if I remove 'Not Found' from browser router. Else, paths collide and redirects to 'Not Found Component'

```
function Search({setSearchResult}) {
   
    const history = useHistory();
    const location = useLocation();
    const searchInput = useRef();

    const params = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
    const q = params.get('q');
    
    function handleSubmit(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        history.push(`/search/search?q=${searchInput.current.value}`)
    }

    useEffect(()=>{
        if(q){
            searchInput.current.value=q ? q : '';

            const productSearch = products.results
            .filter(item => item.title.toLowerCase().includes(q.toLowerCase()))
            .map((item)=>
            <Col sm={4} key={item.id} className="mt-3">
                 <Link to ={`/ProductDetails/${item.id}`} >
                      <Card>
                          <Card.Img variant="top" src={item.src[0]}/>
                          <Card.Body className="text-dark text-center">
                              <Card.Title className="font-secondary">{item.title}</Card.Title>
                              <Card.Text className="font-secondary">
                                  {item.detail}
                              </Card.Text>
                          </Card.Body>
                      </Card>
                 </Link>
                </Col>
              
            );
            setSearchResult(productSearch);
        }
    },[q])
    return (
        <>
            <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit} inline>
               <FormControl 
               htmlFor='search' 
               type="text" 
               id="search"
               placeholder="Search items" 
               ref={searchInput}
               name={q}
               />
                <Button type='submit' id="searchBtn" onClick={handleSubmit} className="font-secondary" >{searchIcon}</Button>    
           </Form>
          
        </>
    )
}
```

export default Search

---

**Result Component**

Search results are displayed in here.

```
function Result({searchResult}) {
        return (
            <>
            <Container>
                <Row className="mt-5">
                <h2 className="font-display">Search Results</h2>
                </Row>
                <Row>
                    {searchResult}
                </Row>
            </Container>
            </>
        )
    }
    
    export default Result
```

So I need to prevent that collision and make components work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React Router will use the first component that it matches in the Switch statement, just like a regular switch statement.

So the NotFound and 404 components should be moved to the end of the Switch component, with search, and whatever other routes you're going to want, above them